# Electron auto update error Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: angular, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I'm using electron-updater package for auto-update the electron application. I'm using private repo with the personal token. The auto update was working fine in some machines. But in some machines, it shows Error: net:: ERR_TIMED_OUT. How to resolve it. I'm using windows 10. I have tried to check whether any firewall block on that machine. But the api.github.com URL was working fine. Unable to found the exact download URL for the update to check in that machine.

Answer (score 0):

In general it means that the updating hasn't finished in time.

Did you check the internet connection on those machines? It could be related to bad/slow internet connection.